# C# .net 5 Web API won't seed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I was making a seeder to my API I follow a video tutorial, but mine won't allow it? I am using VS2019. The objective is when the application will run, it will automatically generate a new database and seeds added. As what I did, I drop my database and run, but as I check in my database server, the database won't add and I got no errors.

This is my class

```
public class Seed
{
    public static async Task SeedUsers(DataContext context)
    {
        if (await context.Users.AnyAsync()) return;
        {
            var userData = await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync("DataStoreEF/Data/UserSeedData.json");
            var users = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<AppUser>>(userData);
            
            foreach(var user in users)
            {
                using var hmac = new HMACSHA512();

                user.UserName = user.UserName.ToLower();
                user.PasswordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("P@ssw0rd"));
                user.PasswordSalt = hmac.Key;

                context.Users.Add(user);
            }

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Under my program class configuration, this is what I did

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
            await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during migration");
        }

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a call to `SeedUsers`

Comment: In your main method I see that you migrate the DB but I don't see that you are deleting it; might this be your issue? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created)

Comment: `Database.MigrateAsync()` works with migrations and [data seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding). It has nothing to do with static method in your example.

Comment: hello i figure it out but its weird i use VS2019 on that time but i tried to use in VSCode it works. i have couple search its connected my startup in VS2019 does'nt have watcher instead in VSCode does have therefore am using vsCode to complete my project. 
but thank you for your help mates